# upper/lower semi-continuous from topological definition via Example

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, semicontinuous-functions

Let me first state the definition of semi-continuous function.

> Let $X$ be a space and $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a real-valued function on $X$. Then $f$ is upper semi-continuous if $f^{-1} (-\infty, a)$ is open for each $a$ in $\mathbb{R}$; $f$ is lower semi-continous if $f^{-1}(a, \infty)$ is open for each $a$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

and I know that

> A function $f$ is continuous iff it is both upper and lower semi-continuous.

First I want to prove
\begin{align}
  f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{x} \quad & x<0, \\
  0 \quad & x=0, \\
  -\frac{1}{x} & x>0.  
  \end{cases}
\end{align}
 is upper semi-continuous.  [From analysis, since $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x) = -\infty < f(0)=0$, I know this function $f$ is upper semi-continuous]

From the topological definition I have
 \begin{align}
   f^{-1} (-\infty, a) = \begin{cases}
      (-\frac{1}{|a|}, 0) \cup (0, \frac{1}{|a|}) \quad & a<0 \\
      (-\infty, 0) \cup (0, \infty) \quad & a=0 \\
      (-\infty, 0) \cup \{0\} \cup (0, \infty) = \mathbb{R} & a \geq 0 
   \end{cases} 
 \end{align}
so any case the inverse image is open so $f$ is upper semi- continuous.

But

\begin{align}
   f^{-1} ( a, \infty) = \begin{cases}
      \phi \quad & a \geq 0 \\
      (-\infty, -\frac{1}{|a|}) \cup \{0\} \cup (\frac{1}{|a|}, \infty)  & a <0 
   \end{cases}  
 \end{align}
this seems also open for arbitrary $a\in \mathbb{R}$...

However this cannot be true since $f$ is not continuous. [$f(0) \neq \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x)$.] What's wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(-\infty, -\frac{1}{|a|}) \cup \{0\} \cup (\frac{1}{|a|}, \infty)$ is not open.

Comment: I see your point.  since $\{0\}$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$, $(-\infty, -\frac{1}{|a|}) \cup \{0\} \cup (\frac{1}{|a|}, \infty)$ is not open.